# How do you create a For loop in Java using netbeans 8.1

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProgAssignment12ForLoop {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
     int time = 0; 
     int speed = 0;
     int distance = 0;

     for (int i = 0, i > 0, i++)
     {
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Please input the speed of the vehicle: ");
         speed = keyboard.nextInt();

         System.out.println("Please input how many hours you've traveled: ");
         time = keyboard.nextInt();

         distance = speed * time;

         System.out.println("the distance you have traveled is " + distance);
         i++;
     } 

     System.out.println("Programmed terminated");

    }

}
```

this is the prompt for the type of program I'm suppose to do. '

Use    FOR loop  to program this problem
The distance a vehicle travels can be calculated as follows:
Distance = speed * time
For example, if a train travels 40 miles-per-hour for three hours, the distance traveled is 120 miles. Write a program that asks for the speed of a vehicle (in miles-per-hour)  and the number of hours it has traveled. It should use a loop to display the distance a vehicle has traveled for each hour of a time perios specified by the user. For example, if a vehicle is traveling at 40 mph for a three-hour time period, it should display a report similar to the one that follows:

Hour 1

Distance Traveled 40

Hour 2

distance traveled 80

hour 3

distance traveled 120

Comment: Please use a "Homework" tag.  Also, there are, perhaps, millions of tutorials on how to create a for loop in Java.  lmgtfy... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: @bertmoog [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) and has been for a long time

Comment: Your question needs to be specific enough. What are you trying to ask? You already used the for loop in your program.

Comment: @Reimeus - Thanks... noted.  On some SE's it's still available.

Comment: `for (int i = 0, i > 0 ...` your condition is never true as `i` starts at 0 so the loop never executes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int time;
    int speed;

    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.println("Please input the speed of the vehicle: ");
        speed = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please input how many hours you've traveled: ");
        time = scan.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= time; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Hour %d\n", i);
            System.out.printf("Distance Traveled %d\n\n", speed * i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Programmed terminated");
}
```